# Finding the closest datetime object that is before a given date in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, min

I've already tried looking this up but honestly the answers talk over my head and I don't really know what they mean. I'm still new-ish to python.

So I have a list of dates and I need to compare them to a date and see which is closest and before. I've tried;
`closestDatetime = min(dates, key=lambda d: abs(date-d))`
which give the closest overall date, and I've tried;
`closestpreviousDatetime = min(dates, key=lambda d: date-d)`
which give the earliest date, not what I want. These are all where dates is the list of dates to search through, and date is the one I'm comparing them with.

Help is much appreciated!

Comment: Nice first question.

Answer (score 2):

So you want the *largest* date that is less than `d`:

```
max([x for x in dates if x < d])
```